# How is this MATLAB code (involving colon operator) resolved?

Tags: matlab, operator-precedence

Recently, I wanted to calculate the next multiple of 5 of several values.
I was very confused by the output of this code, which *should have* done the trick:

```
7:11 - mod(7:11, 5) + 5
ans =
    7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14
```

While the actual working solution was this:

```
(7:11) - mod(7:11, 5) + 5
ans =

    10    10    10    15    15
```

So this seems to be related to operator precedence! But what exactly does the first command do, and why does it output a `(1,8)` vector?

---

Addendum: I have found that the first command can also be written as:

```
7:(11 - mod(7:11, 5) + 5)
```

Which already hints towards the explanation of the observed result, but I am still curious about the whole explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's the list of MATLAB operator precedence](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html)

As you can see, parentheses, `()`, are solved first, meaning that `mod(7:11,5)` will be done first. Then point 6), the addition and subtraction are taken care of from left to right, i.e. `11-mod(7:11,5)` and then `11-mod(7:11,5)+5`. Then point 7), the colon, `:`, gets evaluated, thus `7:11-mod(7:11,5)+5`.

As you noted correctly `7:11 - mod(7:11, 5) + 5`  is the same as `7:(11 - mod(7:11, 5) + 5)`, as seen above using operator precedence.

---

Now to the second part: why do you obtain 8 values, rather than 5? The problem here is "making an array with an array". Basically:

```
1:3
ans =
     1     2     3
1:(3:5)
ans =
     1     2     3
```

This shows what's going on. If you initialise an array with the colon, but have the end point as an *array*, MATLAB uses only the first value. As odd as it may sound, it's [documented behaviour](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html).

`mod(7:11,5)` generates an array, `[2 3 4 0 1]`. This array is then subtracted from `11` and `5` is added `[14 13 12 16 15]`. Now, as we see in the documentation, only the first element is then considered. `7:[14 13 12 16 15]` gets parsed as `7:14` and will result in 8 values, as you've shown.

Doing `(7:11) - mod(7:11, 5) + 5` first creates two arrays: `7:11` and `mod(7:11,5)`. It then subtracts the two arrays elementwise and adds 5 to each of the elements. Interesting to note here would be that `7:12 - mod(7:11, 5) + 5` would work, whereas `(7:12) - mod(7:11, 5) + 5` would result in an error due to incompatible array sizes.

Comment: Wow, very thorough answer! I am still wondering if `7:11 - mod(7:11, 5) + 5 ` should rather throw an error, or at least a warning!? MATLAB silently using only the first value does not seem very intuitive to me, and could cause some hard-to-find errors in a script.

Comment: @rotton there might be some reason to have `1:(3:5)` as valid syntax, all the rest is standard operator precedence. So I don't think a warning should be thrown, as people might actually want this (and it's valid syntax, warnings are usually reserved for stuff as illconditioned matrices, max number of iterations reached etc).

Comment: @rotton [Luis Mendo sent me a doc link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50810361#50810361) which documents the array creating using the colon and arrays as input.